# Turning off the DEM 128064B SYH-PY display

Tags: c, lcd, hal-library, nucleo

I'm trying for warming up to turn off and on the DEM 128064B LCD based on the instructions defined in the [datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/58c47b640ee636cf5a2f433dbafcb0c2/DEM%20128064B%20SYH-PY.pdf) page 12 section 10-1, but I nothing changes and the LCD is on always with all the pixels set as high I think. This is the function that I've written so far to test the functionality. Should I do anything specific? Because I'm new in this area.

```
void display_off() {
    HAL_Delay(50);

    // Sets LCD to active mode
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_RW_GPIO_Port, LCD_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    // Based on documentation to turn LCD on or off
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DI_GPIO_Port, LCD_DI_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_RW_GPIO_Port, LCD_RW_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    HAL_Delay(20);

    // Sets the data bus to turn off the LCD
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB0_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB1_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB2_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB3_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB3_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB4_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB4_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB5_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB5_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB6_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB6_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DB7_GPIO_Port, LCD_DB7_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    HAL_Delay(20);

    // Resets the LCD
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_RW_GPIO_Port, LCD_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

Comment: Setting all those pins one at a time in sequence can surely not be the correct solution. Do a single write to the register. If the clunky "HAL" sits in the way of this, get rid of it.

Comment: You mean low level setting? I don't know how to do that. :)

Comment: It's just plain GPIO, probably the simplest thing you can do in a microcontroller program. So there is no need to have a HAL for it. Correctly written could should look something along the lines of `LCD_PORT = LCD_DB1 | LCD_DB2 | LDC_DB3 | LCD_DB4 | LCD_DB5;` which boils down into a single write.

Comment: Thanks.........